# Neo4j Returns Results @apollo/server does not

Tags: node.js, neo4j, grandstack

I can see the generated query in my vscode terminal with debugging turned on: `DEBUG=@neo4j/graphql:* node index2.js`

```
@neo4j/graphql:execute About to execute Cypher:
Cypher:
MATCH (this:`Business`)
RETURN this { .name } AS this
Params:
{} +45ms
  @neo4j/graphql:execute Execute successful, received 0 records +0ms
```

As you can see no results are returned. However, if I run the exact same query inside the neo4j browser I receive the expected results

```
╒═════════════════════════════════╕
│this                             │
╞═════════════════════════════════╡
│{name: "Market on Front"}        │
├─────────────────────────────────┤
│{name: "Hanabi"}                 │
├─────────────────────────────────┤
│{name: "Zootown Brew"}           │
├─────────────────────────────────┤
│{name: "Missoula Public Library"}│
├─────────────────────────────────┤
│{name: "Ninja Mike's"}           │
├─────────────────────────────────┤
│{name: "KettleHouse Brewing Co."}│
├─────────────────────────────────┤
│{name: "Imagine Nation Brewing"} │
├─────────────────────────────────┤
│{name: "Ducky's Car Wash"}       │
├─────────────────────────────────┤
│{name: "Neo4j"}                  │
└─────────────────────────────────┘
```

The code below is almost exactly copy/pasted from this [github repo](https://github.com/johnymontana/fullstack-graphql-book/blob/main/code/chapter4/index.js) with the exception of upgrading from `apollo-server` to `@apollo/server`

```
const { ApolloServer } = require("@apollo/server");
const { startStandaloneServer } = require('@apollo/server/standalone');
const neo4j = require("neo4j-driver");
const { Neo4jGraphQL } = require("@neo4j/graphql");

const resolvers = {
  Business: {
    waitTime: (obj, args, context, info) => {
      var options = [0, 5, 10, 15, 30, 45];
      return options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];
    },
  },
};

const typeDefs = /* GraphQL */ `
  type Query {
    fuzzyBusinessByName(searchString: String): [Business!]!
      @cypher(
        statement: """
        CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes( 'businessNameIndex', $searchString+'~')
        YIELD node RETURN node
        """
      )
  }

  type Business {
    businessId: ID!
    waitTime: Int! @computed
    averageStars: Float!
      @cypher(
        statement: "MATCH (this)<-[:REVIEWS]-(r:Review) RETURN avg(r.stars)"
      )
    recommended(first: Int = 1): [Business!]!
      @cypher(
        statement: """
        MATCH (this)<-[:REVIEWS]-(:Review)<-[:WROTE]-(:User)-[:WROTE]->(:Review)-[:REVIEWS]->(rec:Business)
        WITH rec, COUNT(*) AS score
        RETURN rec ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT $first
        """
      )
    name: String!
    city: String!
    state: String!
    address: String!
    location: Point!
    reviews: [Review!]! @relationship(type: "REVIEWS", direction: IN)
    categories: [Category!]! @relationship(type: "IN_CATEGORY", direction: OUT)
  }

  type User {
    userID: ID!
    name: String!
    reviews: [Review!]! @relationship(type: "WROTE", direction: OUT)
  }

  type Review {
    reviewId: ID!
    stars: Float!
    date: Date!
    text: String
    user: User! @relationship(type: "WROTE", direction: IN)
    business: Business! @relationship(type: "REVIEWS", direction: OUT)
  }

  type Category {
    name: String!
    businesses: [Business!]! @relationship(type: "IN_CATEGORY", direction: IN)
  }
`;

const driver = neo4j.driver(
  "bolt://localhost:7687",
  neo4j.auth.basic("database", "password") # this is not the default database
);

const neoSchema = new Neo4jGraphQL({ typeDefs, driver });

neoSchema.getSchema().then(async (schema) => {
  const server = new ApolloServer({ schema });
  const { url } = await startStandaloneServer(server, {
    listen: { port: 4000 },
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After too many hours I came up with a list of possible issue(s).

- Is there an error? No
- Is my db running? Yes
- Is my connection correct? Yes as there is an error if I use the wrong password
- Is my schema correct? Uknown: I used the `@neo4j/introspector` to attempt to see what my schema looked like and it returns an empty string. Hmm
- Am I connected to the right DBMS???

I am not using the default neo4j instance that comes by default. I have a separate DBMS that I have installed plugins on and that's what I'm attempting to connect to.

After more searching and dead ends I used the right search terms to get what I was looking for. Here in the [official documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/driver-configuration/) is how to specify which DBMS you want to use. After updating my code like below everything began working as expected.

```
neoSchema.getSchema().then(async (schema) => {
  const server = new ApolloServer({ schema });
  const { url } = await startStandaloneServer(server, {
    listen: { port: 4000 },
    // HERE
    context: async ({ req }) => ({ req, driverConfig: { database: "NOT_DEFAULT_DBMS" } }),
  });
});
```